# Show just first and last marker on path

Tags: google-maps-api-3

For generate markers on google maps I call the function displayLocation with the next code:

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
     displayLocation(data[i]);
}
```

On displayLocation I create an array with all the positions for  the path I want to create and the markers, I just wanna show the first and the last marker on the path.
My displayLocation function looks like:

```
function displayLocation(location){
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.latitud), parseFloat(location.longitud)); 
                if(location.nombreequipo=="AST1"){
                    var path =  new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.latitud), parseFloat(location.longitud));
                    rutaAST1.push(path);
                }

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: imagen,
                    draggable: false,
                    visible: true,
                    title: location.nombreequipo
                });
                arrayMarcadores.push(marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                    infowindow.setContent(content);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
                return marker;
            }
```

In this part of the code I set the path, I call:

```
varBool = true;
dibujaRutaAST1(map, rutaAST1, varBool);
```

And the function is:

```
var ruta = null;
function dibujaRutaAST1(mapa, rutaVar, varBool){
if(!ruta){
    var coordRuta = rutaVar;
    console.log("En función dibujo de rutas AST1: "+rutaVar);
    ruta= new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: mapa,
        path: coordRuta,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3
    });
    console.log(ruta);
}if(varBool){
    ruta.setMap(mapa);
}else{
    ruta.setMap(null);
}
}
```

Iteration on markers array:

```
function mostrarMarcas(nombreEquipo){
                for(var i=0;i<arrayMarcadores.length;i++){
                    if(arrayMarcadores[i].title==nombreEquipo){
                        arrayMarcadores[i].setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any suggestion? 
Thanks.

Comment: In some part of your code you set the path and markers with `setMap()`. Can you show us?

Comment: Ok, I saw your update, but I mean the part where you use any `for` to iterate with `arrayMarcadores`. In this part you can just use the first and last element like `arrayMarcadores[0]` and `arrayMarcadores[arrayMarcadores.length - 1]`.

Comment: Sorry, I forget about that part, thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, not exactly. There is another part you ADD the marker, not set it visible. Something like `arrayMarcadores[i].setMap(mapa)`.

Comment: I must something wrong in my code, is working fine, but I don´t have that part. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have discover that my function displayLocation charge the markers on the map, one by one, so I must correct that part of my code and charge when I have the array ready.

Comment: Thank you so much, now is working, maybe is not the better way, but I have follow your comments and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I just create the first and the last marker from my array with all the points:

```
if(rutaAST1.length!=0){
    dibujaRutaAST1(map, rutaAST1, varBool);
    var imagen ='img/markers/blue_MarkerA.png';
    var markerIniAST1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: rutaAST1[0],
        map: map,
        icon: imagen,
        draggable: false,
        visible: true,
        title: "AST1"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerIniAST1, 'click', function(){
        infowindow.setContent(contentAST1[0]);
        infowindow.open(map, markerIniAST1);
    });
    var markerFinAST1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: rutaAST1[rutaAST1.length-1],
        map: map,
        icon: imagen,
        draggable: false,
        visible: true,
        title: "AST1"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerFinAST1, 'click', function(){
        infowindow.setContent(contentAST1[contentAST1.length-1]);
        infowindow.open(map, markerFinAST1);
    });
}
```

Thank you so much for helping me to clear my mind with this part of my code :)